# How to get request host in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to get request host in django ?
how will I get host URL/name from request

```
class StoreLocations(APIView):
    """
    GET     :  For fetching store locations
    Returns :  Store Locations
    ---------------
    json  
    """
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ["get"]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
            """
            Want to check from where request is coming from and allow requests coming from specific urls only
            """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code snippet to see which host is used.

```py
print(request.environ.get("HTTP_ORIGIN"))
```

To see the additional details present in request.

```py
print(request.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`HttpRequest.get_host(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host)

```py
class StoreLocations(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        host = request.get_host()
```

Answer (score 1):

django request have META dictionary:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

I think you search for:

```
request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] # e.g. '1.1.1.1'
request.META['REMOTE_HOST'] # e.g. '1.1.1.1'
request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] # this show url from where was made request
```